# TVF UDF does not return the same data as SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

Calling the UDF like so:

```
SELECT
       product_name,
       SUM(quantity) AS SumQty,
       SUM(face_value) AS SumFaceValue,
       SUM(net_cost)AS SumNetCost,
       SUM(face_value - net_cost) AS SumScripRebate,
       organization_name
FROM getSalesSummary(@GLSCOrgId, @BeginDate, @EndDate) getSalesSummary
GROUP BY product_name, organization_name
ORDER BY product_name
```

yields:

```
   "Chili's      1    25.00   22.75  2.25   Sample Organization 1
    CVS/pharmacy 1  25.00   23.50  1.50   Sample Organization 1
    Macy's       1  100.00  90.00  10.00  Sample Organization 1"
```

Using the UDF logic and testing the results with SELECT:

```
SELECT 
       product_name,
       SUM(quantity) AS SumQty,
       SUM(face_value) AS SumFaceValue,
       SUM(net_cost) AS SumNetCost,
       SUM(face_value - net_cost) AS SumScripRebate,
       organization_name
FROM @ReturnTable
GROUP BY product_name, organization_name
ORDER BY product_name
```

yields:

```
   "Chili's       4   100.00  91.00   9.00   Sample Organization 1
    CVS/pharmacy  1   25.00   23.50   1.50   Sample Organization 1
    Macy's        1   100.00  90.00   10.00  Sample Organization 1"
```

@ReturnTable is the table returned by the UDF and is created like so:

```
INSERT INTO @ReturnTable(product_name,
                         unit_price,
                         quantity,
                         face_value,
                         net_cost,
                         organization_name)
(select * from @TablePartial UNION select * from @TableClosed)
```

The test with the SELECT and variables is returning the correct data, but calling the UDF is not getting those other 3 Chili's records. I am using the same data for parameters. I'm quite new to UDFs and I'm not sure why it would return different data than what the SELECT does. Any suggestions and/or answers?

Comment: can u generate scripts for tables,data and function and post here it can give more idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need `UNION ALL` not `UNION`

Looking at the two result sets it adds up as though the 4 Chilli's rows are all the same.

```
Chili's      1    25.00   22.75  2.25   Sample Organization 1
Chili's      1    25.00   22.75  2.25   Sample Organization 1
Chili's      1    25.00   22.75  2.25   Sample Organization 1
Chili's      1    25.00   22.75  2.25   Sample Organization 1
-------------------------------------------------------------
Chili's       4   100.00  91.00   9.00   Sample Organization 1
```

Using `UNION` will remove the duplicates leaving you with one row.

Comment: Won't UNION ALL create duplicates? Also, why would that matter? Selecting all from the table and returning the table should give the same results no matter how it's created right?

Comment: `UNION ALL` won't create duplicates. It just won't remove duplicates. Impossible to speculate from here as to why you are getting different results. You would need to add sufficient detail to your question such that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok, I will see what else I am allowed to post, and try the UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is the `UNION` change it to `UNION ALL`  `UNION` will eliminate dups

Run these queries to see the difference

```
select 1 as a
union 
select 1
union 
select 1


select 1 as a
union  all
select 1
union all
select 1
```